# If I refresh the browser my react app are being page not supported error message

Tags: reactjs, react-router, netlify

I'm new in react app development, I just build my practice app and deployed it through Netlify. I can visit my app and everything is fine till I refresh my window. Refreshing the window comes with an error **page not found**. what should I do to solve this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at providing a `_redirects` file in your root directory. See https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/

For example,

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Answer (score 0):

As cra is single page application, you need server setting to redirect everytime to index.html,
You might want to check this link
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/07/creating-better-more-predictable-redirect-rules-for-spas/